# Problema con la Ñ en PHP 5.60.30

Tags: php

Resulta que si pongo una variable con la letra ñ y luego aplico la función de contar los caracteres de la variable, me aparece uno de mas

```
<?php    
$pal="niño";
$long=strlen($pal);
echo"$long";
?>
```

El resultado de la longitud de la variable es 5, sin embargo la variable tiene solo 4 letras, Que solución hay para esto?